# Vi editor: How to find and replace from the matching to end of string

Tags: replace, find, vi

I have string 'TP_PO=010101', then I want to replace that string to 'TP_PO=22', using :%s/TP_PO=*/TP_PO=22/g but it does not work.
Please help me !!!

Answer (score 1):

It's because =* means "0 or more ="

What you wanted to say is =.*  which means "= followed by anything zero or more times"

```
%s/TP_PO=.*/TP_PO=22/g
```